# Rails: How to set different ":message" for each one of the possible errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3

I use this validation:

```
validates_numericality_of :price, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :less_than => 1000000
```

How could I set a different `:message` for each one of the following cases ?

- `price` < 0
- `price` >= 1000000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're using Rails 3, another option you have is to create a custom validator:

```
# You can put this in lib/better_numericality_validator.rb
class BetterNumericalityValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
    def validate_each(record,attribute,value)
        if value < 0
            record.errors[attribute] << "must be greater than or equal to 0"
        elsif value >= 1000000
            record.errors[attribute] << "must be less than 1000000")
        end
    end
end
```

Then you can use your custom validator in your model:

```
# In your model.rb
validates :price, :better_numericality => true
```

This method is very similar to Anubhaw's answer.  But pulling the logic out into the a custom validator makes it so that you can reuse the validation elsewhere easily, you can easily unit test the validator in isolation, and I personally think that `validates :price, :better_numericality => true` leaves your model looking cleaner than the alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following in model.rb:-

```
def validate
  if self.price < 0
      errors.add(:price, "custom message")
  elsif self.price > 1000000
      errors.add(:price, "custom message")
  end
end
```

Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
validates_numericality_of :price, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :message => "Foo"
validates_numericality_of :price, :less_than => 1000000, :message => "Bar"
```

I've not tested it, but it should work?
Alternatively,  Anubhaw's question is a good fallback.

Comment: The problem with this is if I enter `foo`, I'll see both messages (I want to see only the first one).

Answer (score 0):

At some point, you should probably ask yourself whether it isn't time to apply some convention over configuration.

In my opinion, an error message such as "Please enter a valid price greater than 0 and less than 1 million" (or similar) is a perfectly valid solution to the problem. It prevents you from adding unnecessary complexity to your application and allows you to move on to other (presumably more important) features.

Comment: You may want to add custom format, say "should be less than $ 1000", or "3344 is too much people".